# Android compare two fragments

Tags: android, fragment

When I change a fragment I would like to compare the new one with the current one. If they are the same, it is not necessary to replace them.

I tried

```
 public void displayFragment(Fragment fragment){
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment currentFragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.content_frame);
    if(!currentFragment.equals(fragment))
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().addToBackStack(null).replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
}
```

but it does not work and the fragment is changed even if the new one is the same

A solution ?
Thanks

**EDIT**

The solution :

```
public void displayFragment(Fragment fragment){
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment currentFragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.content_frame);
    if(!fragment.getClass().toString().equals(currentFragment.getTag())){
        getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .addToBackStack(null)
        .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment, fragment.getClass().toString()) // add and tag the new fragment
        .commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: if it is in same class??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way to identify Fragments is to give them tags :

```
public void displayFragment(Fragment fragment, String tag){
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment currentFragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.content_frame);
    if(!tag.equals(currentFragment.getTag())
        getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .addToBackStack(null)
        .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment, tag) // add and tag the new fragment
        .commit();
}
```

edit : alternative version from **psv**'s comment, using classnames as tag :

```
public void displayFragment(Fragment fragment){ 
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment currentFragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.content_frame);
    if(!fragment.getClass().toString().equals(currentFragment.getTag()))
    { 
        getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .addToBackStack(null)
        .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment, fragment.getClass().toString()) // add and tag the new fragment
        .commit(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes ! Thank you very much !
And to avoid to put a tag each time I change the fragment, I modified your code in
public void displayFragment(Fragment fragment){
     FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
     Fragment currentFragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.content_frame);
     if(!fragment.getClass().toString().equals(currentFragment.getTag())){
         getSupportFragmentManager()
         .beginTransaction()
         .addToBackStack(null)
         .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment, fragment.getClass().toString()) // add and tag the new fragment
         .commit();
     }
 }

Comment: Or you could just use `instanceof`? Keep it simple.

Answer (score 0):

Working Simple code in Kotlin. Here Fragment_Current() is a current fragment.

```
 fun displayFragment(fm: Fragment) {
    if(fm !is Fragment_Current){
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.ContentFragmentRoot, fm).commit()
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Based on @alex-fu comment, the code should be something like this:

```
public void displayFragment(Fragment fragment){

    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment currentFragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.content_frame);

    if( !(fragment instanceof currentFragment) ) { 
        getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment, fragment.getClass().toString()) // add and tag the new fragment
            .commit(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: The `instanceof` is used to check if an object is of a particular class or interface type. But you try to check two objects. It should look like this: `if(!(fragment instanceof FragmentClassName)) `

Comment: For Kotlin it goes like this... if (fragment !is FragmentClassName)